# How to code the same SHA256Encript.php on dart?

Tags: php, dart, encryption, hash, sha

I have this class on php:

```
{
    public function Generate($ipAddress, $secretKey, $comercio, $sucursal, $amount)
    {
        $input = sprintf("%s*%s*%s*%s*%s", $ipAddress, $comercio, $sucursal, $amount, $secretKey);
        $inputArray = utf8_encode($input);
        $hashedArray = unpack('C*', hash( "sha256", $inputArray, true));
        $string = null;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= count($hashedArray); $i++) {
            $string .= str_pad(strtolower(dechex($hashedArray[$i])), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
        return $string;
    }
}
```

And I need to do exactly the same on flutter, using .dart.
I tried:

```
    var input = ("$ipAddress*$secretKey*$comercio*$sucursal*$amount");

    var inputArray = utf8.encode(input); // I get an array with numbers here, while in php
    // I get the same string

    var hashedArray = sha256.convert(inputArray); //need unpack
```

And how to code

```
$string .= str_pad(strtolower(dechex($hashedArray[$i])), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

on dart?

Thanks!

Comment: There's literally no sense in manually converting the binary hash to a byte array and then into a hex string in PHP. `hash( "sha256", $inputArray, false)` will return the hex string.

Answer (score 0):

That php for loop is just encoding into hex, right?

There's a hex codec in Dart, in the [convert](https://pub.dev/packages/convert) package (note: not `dart:convert`). Add that to pubspec.yaml, import it at the top of your source file, then:

```
final hexString = hex.encode(hashedArray);
```